# Drop rows with multiple keys in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`.

df1:

```
contig  position   tumor_f  t_ref_count  t_alt_count
1     14599  0.000000            1            0
1     14653  0.400000            3            2
1     14907  0.333333            6            3
1     14930  0.363636            7            4
```

df2:

```
contig  position
1     14599
1     14653
```

I would like to remove the rows from df1 with matching contig, position values in df2. Something akin to: `df1[df1[['contig','position']].isin(df2[['contig','position']])]`
Except this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Version .13 is adding an `isin` method to DataFrame that will accomplish this.  If you're using the current master you can try:

```
In [46]: df1[['contig', 'position']].isin(df2.to_dict(outtype='list'))
Out[46]: 
  contig position
0   True     True
1   True     True
2   True    False
3   True    False
```

To get the elements not contained use `~` for not and index

```
In [45]: df1.ix[~df1[['contig', 'position']].isin(df2.to_dict(outtype='list')).
all(axis=1)]
Out[45]: 
   contig  position   tumor_f  t_ref_count  t_alt_count
2       1     14907  0.333333            6            3
3       1     14930  0.363636            7            4
```

Comment: Andy if you read this, what are you thoughts on `isin` accepting another dataframe (that has to be similarly indexed) to remove the need for the df2.to_dict?  Using to_dict isn't terrible, but it looks like @user1867185 was expecting a dataframe to work.

Comment: a DF is dict-like so shouldn't be hard to do

Comment: We didn't put it in 0.12 in case there were API changes, looks like there could be :) do you mind putting together a github issue for this? excitingly I get a segfault when doing something similar...

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am apparently using 0.12.0 that I installed few minutes back using "pip install pandas". I only attempted the first solution you proposed and that yielded "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'isin'."

Comment: @AndyHayden I'll start an issue.

@user1867185 The `isin` method is new to .13, which isn't officially released yet.  I think pip has the ability to install from github repositories. pandas' is located at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the Series [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) twice (works in 0.12):

```
In [21]: df1['contig'].isin(df2['contig']) & df1['position'].isin(df2['position'])
Out[21]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

In [22]: ~(df1['contig'].isin(df2['contig']) & df1['position'].isin(df2['position']))
Out[22]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

In [23]: df1[~(df1['contig'].isin(df2['contig']) & df1['position'].isin(df2['position']))]
Out[23]:
   contig  position   tumor_f  t_ref_count  t_alt_count
2       1     14907  0.333333            6            3
3       1     14930  0.363636            7            4
```

*Perhaps we can get a neat solution in 0.13 (using DataFrame's `isin` like in Tom's answer).*

It feel like there ought to be a neat way to do this using an inner [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.merge.html)...

```
In [31]: pd.merge(df1, df2, how="inner")
Out[31]:
   contig  position  tumor_f  t_ref_count  t_alt_count
0       1     14599      0.0            1            0
1       1     14653      0.4            3            2
```

Comment: Feels like ought to be a neat merge way

Answer (score 1):

Here's a verbose approach:

```
iter1 = df1[['contig', 'position']].itertuples()
is_in_other_df = []
for row in iter1:
    tup2 = df2.itertuples()
    is_in_other_df.append(row in tup2)
df1["InOtherDF"] = is_in_other_df
```

Then just drop rows where "InOtherDF" is `True`. You might have to adjust it slightly to ignore the index when giving back the row-tuples.

I think this is a cleaner way using `merge`

```
df2["FromDF2"] = True
df1 = pandas.merge(df1, df2, left_on=["contig", "position"], 
                   right_on=["contig", "position"], how="left")
df1[~df1.FromDF2]
```

Comment: Feels like there ought to be neater way to do anti-join!